# SQlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I don't know what's best for me at the moment. I want a part in my app were the users enter their post code in a field box. The data will call company near them once entered.

So I don't know where to start because I have been reading about databases in android. Some people say that SQLite isn't any good. If you can help me and tell me what's best to use.

Thanks people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the local SQLite on your device is a good choice to go when the data kind of static, that means it is not changing or expanding a lot. You don't generate too much network trafic. But consider that you have to download the data once from a server, handle changes made on the server, etc. So if your data changes a lot, querying the server database might be better.

Answer (score 1):

use web services instead of SQlite .

Access MySQL or any other data base using json or xml web services.

For that you have to make webservices using php ,ruby on rails,.NET or any other server side programming language.